# Add/Remove related Entities to an objects List<Entity>

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, many-to-many, entity-framework-5

Ok first my actual Book and Author Object definitions:

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int BookID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public virtual String Title { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public virtual String Abstract { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"\d{4}")]
    public virtual String Year { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Genre")]
    public virtual int GenreID { get; set; }

    public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Author> Authors { get; set; }

    public Book()
    {
        Authors = new List<Author>();
    }
}

public class Genre
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int GenreID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public virtual String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int AuthorID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public virtual String Firstname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public virtual String Lastname { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Book> Books { get; set; }

    public Author()
    {
        Books = new List<Book>();
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public string Fullname 
    {
        get { return String.Format("{0}, {1}", Lastname, Firstname); }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Fullname;
    }
}
```

Using EF-Migrations I get a configuration.cs file into which I entered my Data-Seed and then using add-migration to get the first migration to initialize the database EF properly creates the according tables Authors, Books, Genres and last but not least AuthorBooks to hold the many-to-many relations between books and authors.

So far I got my whole demo application working. The only problem I have is that Entity Framework seems to refuse saving the AuthorBooks relations. I've set my app up so that at book-creation/editing I can choose the related Authors via a MultiSelectList-ListBox.

BookControllerViewModel:

```
public class BookControllerViewModel
{
    public Book actualBook { get; set; }
    public String redirectUrl { get; set; }
    public MultiSelectList Authors { get; set; }
    public int[] AuthorIDs { get; set; }
    public SelectList Genres { get; set; }
}
```

The ViewModel contains the book that is subject to the create/edit operation, the MultiSelectList of Authors with proper Selection-Info based on the book and I added int[] AuthorIDs to hold the selected IDs the user would select in the ListBox of the Create/Edit view.

```
@model BookStoreInternet.ViewModels.BookControllerViewModel

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.actualBook.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.actualBook.Title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.actualBook.Title)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <label>Author@( Model.actualBook.Authors.Count > 1 ? "s" :"" )</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.ListBox("AuthorIDs", Model.Authors)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.actualBook.Authors)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.actualBook.Abstract)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.actualBook.Abstract)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.actualBook.Abstract)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.actualBook.Year)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.actualBook.Year)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.actualBook.Year)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.actualBook.GenreID, "Genre")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("actualBook.GenreID", Model.Genres)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.actualBook.GenreID)
    </div>
```

That too works well in that the ViewModel that is posted to the controller-Action

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(BookControllerViewModel bookVM)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            bookVM.actualBook.Authors = db.Authors.Where(x => bookVM.AuthorIDs.Contains(x.AuthorID)).ToList();
            db.Entry(bookVM.actualBook).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Redirect(bookVM.redirectUrl);
        }

        bookVM.Authors = new MultiSelectList(db.Authors, "AuthorID", "Fullname", bookVM.actualBook.Authors.Select(x => x.AuthorID));
        bookVM.Genres = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreID", "Name", bookVM.actualBook.GenreID);

        return View(bookVM);
    }
```

is properly filled with the values I would expect. What does not work though is that db.SaveChanges() seems to "silently" refuse to save the authors I added to the book. 
Debugging the operation I can see that bookVM.ActualBook.Authors is actually set properly and contains the selected Authors... but the according entries to the Jointable AuthorBooks are not created...

Would anyone have an idea why this doesn't work or maybe even how to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

---

Thanks to **Gerts** answers I got this working by modifying the Controller-Action to

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(BookControllerViewModel bookVM)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var book = db.Books.Find(bookVM.actualBook.BookID);
            book.Update(bookVM.actualBook);
            book.Authors.Clear();
            foreach(var aid in bookVM.AuthorIDs)
                book.Authors.Add(db.Authors.Find(aid));
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Redirect(bookVM.redirectUrl);
        }

        bookVM.Authors = new MultiSelectList(db.Authors, "AuthorID", "Fullname", bookVM.actualBook.Authors.Select(x => x.AuthorID));
        bookVM.Genres = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreID", "Name", bookVM.actualBook.GenreID);

        return View(bookVM);
    }
```

and adding a method to the Book model

```
    internal void Update(Book book)
    {
        Title = book.Title;
        Abstract = book.Abstract;
        Year = book.Year;
        GenreID = book.GenreID;
    }
```

Thanks again to Gert!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Book-Author is a many to many association you have to load `actualBook.Authors` first for the change tracker to be able to notice changes. Then you can add/remove items from it or replace it by a new collection. Setting its state is not necessary.

Comment: That was WAY TOO EASY ... :-) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually that only solves the ADD ITEMS part... I can add more and more authors this way, but unselected authors wont be removed... although I tried to 
`   var book = db.Books.First(x => x.BookID == bookVM.actualBook.BookID);
    book.Authors = new List<Author>();
    db.SaveChanges();`
Do you have an idea about what to do to also REMOVE ITEMS?

Comment: Probably you better clear the (loaded) Authors first and then add the ones that should be there. That's what I tend to do with many-to-many. It's just a bunch of junction records that can easily be replaced. But I thought that replacing the list would work.

Comment: Ok, I finally got this working. Thanks a lot again. But somehow EF seems a tad strange... at least from my experiences... I mean I still might be doing something wrong. I updated my question with my working solution. Maybe you'd have another spare comment? TIA!

Comment: The need for `SaveChanges` twice looks strange indeed. And a bit dangerous, because you may lose data. I think you should `Add()` the authors to `book.Authors` in stead of replacing the collection.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts... And Thank you very much for the idea. Using Add() to add the authors after clearing book.Authors indeed works. Thank you very much. I will probably just keep wondering why replacing the list does not ... guess to find the answer to that I will have to dig deeper into the inner workings of EF.